# How to use Castle Windsor's PerWebRequest lifestyle with OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, castle-windsor, perwebrequest

I am converting an existing ASP .Net Web API 2 project to use OWIN. The project uses Castle Windsor as the dependency injection framework with one of the dependencies set to use the PerWebRequest lifestyle.

When I make a request to the server I get a `Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentResolutionException` exception. The exception recommends adding the following to the `system.web/httpModules` and `system.WebServer/modules` sections in the config file:

```
<add name="PerRequestLifestyle"
     type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
```

This doesn't resolve the error.

Taking inspiration from the example provided by SimpleInjector's OWIN integration, I attempted to set a scope in the OWIN startup class (as well as update the dependency's lifestyle) using:

```
appBuilder.User(async (context, next) =>
{
    using (config.DependencyResolver.BeginScope()){
    {
        await next();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this hasn't worked either.

How can I use Castle Windsor's PerWebRequest lifestyle or simulate it in OWIN?

Answer (score 8):

According to the Castle Windsor documentation you can implement your own custom scope. You have to implement the `Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.Scoped.IScopeAccessor` interface.

You then specify your scope accessor when registering your component:

```
Container.Register(Component.For<MyScopedComponent>().LifestyleScoped<OwinWebRequestScopeAccessor >());
```

The class `OwinWebRequestScopeAccessor` implements Castle.Windsor's `IScopeAccessor`:

```
using Castle.MicroKernel.Context;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.Scoped;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Web.Api.Host
{
    public class OwinWebRequestScopeAccessor : IScopeAccessor
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
            var scope = PerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware.YieldScope();
            if (scope != null)
            {
                scope.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public ILifetimeScope GetScope(CreationContext context)
        {
            return PerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware.GetScope();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see `OwinWebRequestScopeAccessor` delegates the calls to **GetScope** and **Dispose** to `PerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware`.

The class `PerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware` is the OWIN counter part of Castle Windsor's ASP.NET IHttpModule [PerWebRequestLifestyleModule](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/Lifestyle/PerWebRequestLifestyleModule.cs).

This is the `PerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware` class:

```
using Castle.MicroKernel;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.Scoped;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Web.Api.Host
{
    using AppFunc = Func<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>;

    public class PerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware
    {
        private readonly AppFunc _next;
        private const string c_key = "castle.per-web-request-lifestyle-cache";
        private static bool _initialized;

        public PerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware(AppFunc next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> environment)
        {
            var requestContext = OwinRequestScopeContext.Current;
            _initialized = true;

            try
            {
                await _next(environment);
            }
            finally
            {
                var scope = GetScope(requestContext, createIfNotPresent: false);
                if (scope != null)
                {
                    scope.Dispose();
                }
                requestContext.EndRequest();
            }
        }

        internal static ILifetimeScope GetScope()
        {
            EnsureInitialized();
            var context = OwinRequestScopeContext.Current;
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(typeof(OwinRequestScopeContext).FullName +".Current is null. " +
                    typeof(PerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware).FullName +" can only be used with OWIN.");
            }
            return GetScope(context, createIfNotPresent: true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns current request's scope and detaches it from the request 
        /// context. Does not throw if scope or context not present. To be 
        /// used for disposing of the context.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        internal static ILifetimeScope YieldScope()
        {
            var context = OwinRequestScopeContext.Current;
            if (context == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var scope = GetScope(context, createIfNotPresent: false);
            if (scope != null)
            {
                context.Items.Remove(c_key);
            }
            return scope;
        }

        private static void EnsureInitialized()
        {
            if (_initialized)
            {
                return;
            }
            throw new ComponentResolutionException("Looks like you forgot to register the OWIN middleware " + typeof(PerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware).FullName);
        }

        private static ILifetimeScope GetScope(IOwinRequestScopeContext context, bool createIfNotPresent)
        {
            ILifetimeScope candidates = null;
            if (context.Items.ContainsKey(c_key))
            {
                candidates = (ILifetimeScope)context.Items[c_key];
            }
            else if (createIfNotPresent)
            {
                candidates = new DefaultLifetimeScope(new ScopeCache());
                context.Items[c_key] = candidates;
            }
            return candidates;
        }
    }

    public static class AppBuilderPerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Use <see cref="PerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app">Owin app.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static IAppBuilder UsePerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware(this IAppBuilder app)
        {
            return app.Use(typeof(PerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware));
        }
    }
}
```

Castle Windsor's ASP.NET IHttpModule `PerWebRequestLifestyleModule` utilizes `HttpContext.Current` for storing the Castle Windsor `ILifetimeScope` on a per-web-request basis. `PerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware` class uses `OwinRequestScopeContext.Current`. This is based on the idea of [Yoshifumi Kawai](https://github.com/neuecc/OwinRequestScopeContext/).

The implementation of `OwinRequestScopeContext` below is my lightweight implementation of Yoshifumi Kawai's original `OwinRequestScopeContext`.

---

Note: if you don't want this lightweight implementation you can use Yoshifumi Kawai's excellent original implementation by running this command in the NuGet Package Manager Console:

`PM> Install-Package OwinRequestScopeContext`

---

Lightweight implementation of `OwinRequestScopeContext`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Web.Api.Host
{
    public interface IOwinRequestScopeContext
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> Items { get; }
        DateTime Timestamp { get; }
        void EndRequest();
    }

    public class OwinRequestScopeContext : IOwinRequestScopeContext
    {
        const string c_callContextKey = "owin.reqscopecontext";
        private readonly DateTime _utcTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        private ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _items = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the <see cref="IOwinRequestScopeContext"/> object 
        /// for the current HTTP request.
        /// </summary>
        public static IOwinRequestScopeContext Current
        {
            get
            {
                var requestContext = CallContext.LogicalGetData(c_callContextKey) as IOwinRequestScopeContext;
                if (requestContext == null)
                {
                    requestContext = new OwinRequestScopeContext();
                    CallContext.LogicalSetData(c_callContextKey, requestContext);
                }
                return requestContext;
            }
            set
            {
                CallContext.LogicalSetData(c_callContextKey, value);
            }
        }

        public void EndRequest()
        {
            CallContext.FreeNamedDataSlot(c_callContextKey);
        }

        public IDictionary<string, object> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return _items;
            }
        }

        public DateTime Timestamp
        {
            get
            {
                return _utcTimestamp.ToLocalTime();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you have all the pieces in place you can tie things up. In your OWIN startup class call the `appBuilder.UsePerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware();` extension method to register the OWIN middle ware defined above. Do this before `appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);`:

```
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Castle.Windsor;
using System.Web.Http.Dispatcher;
using System.Web.Http.Tracing;

namespace Web.Api.Host
{
    class Startup
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

        public Startup()
        {
            _container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new WindsorInstaller());
        }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            var properties = new Microsoft.Owin.BuilderProperties.AppProperties(appBuilder.Properties);
            var token = properties.OnAppDisposing;
            if (token != System.Threading.CancellationToken.None)
            {
                token.Register(Close);
            }

            appBuilder.UsePerWebRequestLifestyleOwinMiddleware();

            //
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            //
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            if (_container != null)
                _container.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The sample WindsorInstaller class shows how you can use the OWIN per-web-request scope:

```
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration;
using Castle.Windsor;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Web.Api.Host
{
    class WindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Component
                .For<IPerWebRequestDependency>()
                .ImplementedBy<PerWebRequestDependency>()
                .LifestyleScoped<OwinWebRequestScopeAccessor>());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<Controllers.V1.TestController>()
                .LifeStyle.Transient);
        }
    }
}
```

The solution I have laid out above is based on the existing `/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/Lifestyle/PerWebRequestLifestyleModule.cs` and Yoshifumi Kawai'soriginal `OwinRequestScopeContext`.

Comment: Interesting - I see this stores `OwinRequestScopeContext` in `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext`. My first thought would have been to  to store this in the Owin environment dictionary. (`OwinContext.Environment`).

Comment: Though on further examination I think I can see a reason: `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext` has globally accessible static members, but there's no safe way to statically acquire `OwinContext`.

Answer (score 6):

I tried implementing [Johan Boonstra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36795780/25216), but found it wasn't working once we got to the ASP.NET MVC Controller methods.

Here's a simpler solution:

First, create some Owin middleware that sits at the start of the pipeline and creates a `DefaultLifetimeScope`

```cs
public class WebRequestLifestyleMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public const string EnvironmentKey = "WindsorOwinScope";

    public WebRequestLifestyleMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope = new DefaultLifetimeScope();
        context.Environment[EnvironmentKey] = lifetimeScope;
        try
        {
            await this.Next.Invoke(context);
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Environment.Remove(EnvironmentKey);
            lifetimeScope.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Insert it at the beginning of the pipeline in your startup configuration:

```cs
public void Configure(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    appBuilder.Use<WebRequestLifestyleMiddleware>();

    //
    // Further configuration
    //
}
```

Now you create a class that implements `IScopeAccessor` and fetches the scope that `WebRequestLifestyleMiddleware` pushed into the environment:

```cs
public class OwinWebRequestScopeAccessor : IScopeAccessor
{
    void IDisposable.Dispose() { }

    ILifetimeScope IScopeAccessor.GetScope(CreationContext context)
    {
        IOwinContext owinContext = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
        string key = WebRequestLifestyleMiddleware.EnvironmentKey;
        return owinContext.Environment[key] as ILifetimeScope;
    }
}
```

Finally, use this scope accessor when registering component lifetimes. For example, I have my custom component called `AccessCodeProvider` which I want to reuse throughout one request:

```cs
container.Register(
      Component.For<AccessCodeProvider>()
               .LifestyleScoped<OwinRequestScopeAccessor>()
);
```

In this case, `AccessCodeProvider` will be created the first time it's asked for within a request, and then reused throughout the web request, finally disposed of when `WebRequestLifestyleMiddleware` invokes `lifetimeScope.Dispose()`.

Comment: I found this very helpful, but in my case I was using self-hosted and HttpContext.Current didn't work for me...  Instead I used the `OwinRequestScopeContext` nuget package (https://github.com/neuecc/OwinRequestScopeContext/)  then I just had to modify the line to get the OwinContext to `IOwinContext owinContext = new Microsoft.Owin.OwinContext(OwinRequestScopeContext.Current.Environment);` and it worked.

Comment: Works well for me, except I had threading issues.  `DefaultLifetimeScope` should be replaced with [ThreadSafeDefaultLifetimeScope](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/implementing-custom-scope.md#the-scope-abstraction-ilifetimescope) since this is a multi threaded enviornment..

Answer (score 1):

I have created PerScope lifestyle behaving like PerWebRequest in a web api application which uses owin middlewares and castle windsor as IoC of the application.

First of all let's make our windsor container as the IoC of the web api application as following:

```
    public class WindsorHttpDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

        public WindsorHttpDependencyResolver(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }
            this.container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type t)
        {
            return this.container.Kernel.HasComponent(t)
             ? this.container.Resolve(t) : null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type t)
        {
            return this.container.ResolveAll(t).Cast<object>().ToArray();
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return new WindsorDependencyScope(this.container);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }//end WindsorHttpDependencyResolver 

  public class WindsorDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer container;
        private readonly IDisposable scope;

        public WindsorDependencyScope(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            if (container == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");

            this.container = container;
        }

        public object GetService(Type t)
        {
            return this.container.Kernel.HasComponent(t)
                ? this.container.Resolve(t) : null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type t)
        {
            return this.container.ResolveAll(t).Cast<object>().ToArray();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.scope?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Then during application's startup let's register it:

```
container.Register(Component.For<System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver>().ImplementedBy<WindsorHttpDependencyResolver>().LifestyleSingleton());
```

Now inside the first middleware(which will be the first and the last middleware will be executed) let's begin scope when new request comes to our web api and dispose it when it ends as following:

```
public class StartinMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{

    public StartinMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
        if (next == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("next");
        }
    }


    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {

        this.Log().Info("Begin request");
        IDisposable scope = null;            
        try
        {
            // here we are using IoCResolverFactory which returns 
            // the instance of IoC container(which will be singleton for the 
            // whole application)
            var ioCResolver= IoCResolverFactory.GetOrCreate();
            //here we are starting new scope
            scope = ioCResolver.BeginScope();

            await Next.Invoke(context);

            this.Log().Info("End request");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
          //here you can log exceptions
        }
        finally
        {
            //here we are desposing scope
            scope?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The code of IoC factory will be something like this:

```
public static class IoCResolverFactory
{
    public static IoCResolver iocResolver;

    public static IoCResolver GetOrCreate()
    {
        if (iocResolver != null)
            return iocResolver;

        iocResolver = new IoCResolver();
        return iocResolver;
    }
}// end IoCResolverFactory

public class IoCResolver
{
    private static WindsorContainer container;

    public IoCResolver()
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer();

        container.Register(Component.For<IoCResolver>().Instance(this).LifestyleSingleton());
        container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(container).LifestyleSingleton());
    }


    public IDisposable BeginScope()
    {
        return container.BeginScope();
    }


    public IDisposable GetCurrentScope()
    {
        return Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.Scoped.CallContextLifetimeScope.ObtainCurrentScope();
    }


    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return container.Resolve<T>();
    }

    public IList<T> ResolveAll<T>()
    {
        return container.ResolveAll<T>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When registering your services during startup you can register them to be resolved per scope as following:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ICurrentRequestService>().ImplementedBy<CurrentRequestService>().LifestyleScoped());
```